# Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_result()?

Tags: php, pdo, phpass

I keep getting this error message and don't know why.  It is a login script and I copied form [here](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords) because I didn't know how to do the login using PHPASS.  Here is my code:

```
$email      = ($_POST['email']);
$pass       = ($_POST['pass']);

require 'connect.php';
require 'PasswordHash.php';
$hash = '*';
    $login = $con->prepare("SELECT password FROM basicuserinfo WHERE email=:email");
    $login->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $login->execute();
    $login->bind_result($hash);
    if (!$login->fetch() && $con->errno)
        die();
    if ($hasher->CheckPassword($pass, $hash)) {
        $what = 'Authentication succeeded';
    } else {
        $what = 'Authentication failed';
    }
    unset($hasher);
```

Comment: `bind_result` or `bindResult` do NOT exist for PDO.

Comment: `bind_result()` is a `mysqli_statement` method, not needed (or valid) for PDO.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend copy/pasting code you don't understand. Read through it, and try to figure out what's going on, and then you might be able to debug it.

Comment: I read through it a bunch, and changed some, and I understand whats going on, but I didn't know what 'bind_result()' does.  I know its bad practice to copy and paste code, but I just didn't know how to do this one on my own.  Usually I copy and paste it, figure out whats going on and how it works, then re-write my own way.  So what do I use instead of 'bind_result()' to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the link that you [have given](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords), they are using [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) connection for MySQL related tasks. The method `bind_result` is one of them methods in `mysqli`.

This is neither needed nor necessary in [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) method of MySQL connections. Here's a [list of valid methods/constructors and classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) etc. for PDO.

---

What you should instead use here is:

```
$hash = $login->fetchColumn();
```

where [`fetchColumn`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) returns a single column from the next row of a result set.